# Open different new view controllers by clicking different elements in table view cell - Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8

My table view cell displays an entity with two different button elements. I want to be able to launch a view controller that displays a selection of food items if I click on the first button and a different view controller that displays a selection of beverages when I click on the second button.

I am able to correctly pass the data to the new view controllers, but can't seem to dismiss the current view and load the new one. My code is like this:

In the table view cell

```
    @IBAction func foodBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("foodBtn pressed")
    print("customer is \(customer?.name)")
    vc.loadChooserScreen(toChoose: "Food", forCustomer: customer!)
}

@IBAction func beverageBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("beverageBtn pressed")
    print("customer is \(customer?.name)")
    vc.loadChooserScreen(toChoose: "Beverage", forCustomer: customer!)
}
```

In the table view controller

```
    func loadChooserScreen(toChoose: String, forCustomer: Customer) {
    print("Choose \(toChoose)")
    print("For \(forCustomer.name)")

    if toChoose == "Food" {
        let foodVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foodMenu") as? FoodVC
            foodVC?.loadCustomerToEdit(customer: forCustomer)
            dismissVC(sender: Any.self)
     }

    else if toChoose == "Beverage" {
        let beverageVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "beverageMenu") as? BeverageVC
        beverageVC?.loadCustomerToEdit(customer: forCustomer)
        dismissVC(sender: Any.self)
    }

    else {
        // do nothing
    }

}
    func dismissVC(sender: Any) {
    print("Reached dismissVC function in selectionMenu")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.delegate!.dismissViewController()
    })
}
```

In this view controller I also have the following protocol

```
protocol OrderVCProtocol {
func dismissViewController()
}
```

and have defined

```
var delegate: OrderVCProtocol!
```

In my root view controller

```
    func dismissViewController() {
    print("Reached dismissViewController function in rootView")
    if let foodVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foodMenu") {
        self.present(foodVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if let beverageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "beverageMenu") {
        self.present(beverageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And the delegate is set when the table view controller is called here

```
    @IBAction func loadOrderView(_ sender: Any) {
    let orderVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderView") as! OrderVC
    orderVC.delegate = self
    self.present(orderVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Within my target view controllers I have the following function

```
func loadCustomerToEdit(customer: Customer) {
    self.customerToEdit = customer
    print("IN FoodVC THE CUSTOMER TO EDIT IS \(self.customerToEdit.name)")
}
```

and a corresponding one in the BeverageVC.

When I run the app, no errors are thrown and I get the following sample output in the console from my print statements:

> foodBtn pressed
>
> customer is Optional("John")
>
> Choose Food
>
> For Optional("John")
>
> IN FoodVC THE CUSTOMER TO EDIT IS Optional("John")
>
> Reached dismissVC function in selectionMenu

and a corresponding response if the beverage button is clicked.

Then nothing happens. So I know the data is correctly being passed to the new view controllers but I don't know how to dismiss the current screen and display the new one with the choices.

I hope my question is clear enough? I'm not sure what's wrong, but the console output clearly shows that the code runs fine until it tries to dismiss the current view.

EDITED TO ADD:

If I modify my dismissVC function in my tableview controller like this:

```
func dismissVC(sender: Any) {
print("Reached dismissVC function in selectionMenu")
delegate.dismissViewController()
}
```

the console view now throws

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And if I modify it again to the following, It goes back to throwing no errors and getting stuck at the same place (i.e. printing the line "Stuck where delegate dismisses view"), showing that the delegate is still nil... but why is it nil when I'd set it in the root view and loaded it in this view?

```
func dismissVC(sender: Any) {
print("Reached dismissVC function in selectionMenu")
if delegate != nil {
    delegate?.dismissViewController()
    } else {
print("Stuck where delegate dismisses view")
}
```

Comment: Is `self.storyboard` nil in your root view controller?

Comment: I made a mistake when transcribing the last line of the console output, but have fixed it now. The code execution doesn't actually reach the root view controller after all. I have no idea why.

Comment: Sounds like `delegate` is nil - do you set it in your root view controller?

Comment: I did set the delegate in the root view controller.

Comment: Can you show the root view controller code where you set the delegate.  Thanks.

Comment: I did. It's in the main question, under the part about the root view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by implementing notifications via notification centre and delegates. Firstly, in my AppDelegate file I added this line at the bottom

```
let notifyCnt = NotificationCenter.default
```

Next, I modified my tableview cell functions to this

```
@IBAction func foodBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
notifyCnt.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toChoose"), object: nil, userInfo: ["toChoose": "Food", "forCustomer": customer])
}

@IBAction func beverageBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    notifyCnt.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toChoose"), object: nil, userInfo: ["toChoose": "Beverage", "forCustomer": customer])
}
```

Then, in the tableview controller I modified it to this:

```
protocol ChooserViewDelegate: class {
func loadChooserView(choice: String, forCustomer: Customer)
}
```

and defined

```
weak var delegate: ChooserViewDelegate?
```

and added this within my ViewDidLoad section

```
notifyCnt.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "toChoose"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: loadChooserScreen)
```

and finally modified my chooser function like so:

```
func loadChooserScreen(notification: Notification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let toChoose = userInfo["toChoose"] as? String,
        let planToEdit = userInfo["customer"] as? Customer else {
            print("No userInfo found in notification")
            return
    }
    delegate?.loadChooserView(choice: toChoose, forCustomer: customer)
}
```

Then in my root view controller I have the following to replace what I had earlier:

```
/*Conform to ChooserViewDelegate Protocol */
func loadChooserView(choice: String, forCustomer: Customer) {
  self.customer = forCustomer
  dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
    if choice == "Food" {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "food", sender: self.customer)
      }
    if choice == "Beverage" {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "beverage", sender: self.customer)
      }
  })
}
```

and I send over the data via prepareForSegue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "food" {
        if let foodVC = segue.destination as? FoodVC {
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "food")
            foodVC.customerToEdit = self.customerToEdit
            foodVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    if segue.identifier == "beverage" {
        if let beverageVC = segue.destination as? BeverageVC {
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "beverage")
            beverageVC.customerToEdit = self.customerToEdit
            beverageVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

So now everything loads and views correctly :)